# Chef cookbook - copy complete directory from files/default location in cookbook to a new location

Tags: chef-infra

I am a beginner to Chef. Can any one please advise if there is a way to copy a directory inside cookbook's `files/default` directory to a different location.

E.g. I have a directory structure with files `a.txt` and `b.txt` in `files/` directory as follows `cookbook_name/files/default/folder-name/[a.txt,b.txt]`. I want them both files to be a location `/home/user/work/somelocation/folder-name/[a.txt,b.txt]`

I have tried [cookbook_file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) resource as follows:

```rb
cookbook_file '/home/user/work/somelocation/' do
  source ['folder-name']
  mode "0644"
  action :create
end
```

and

```
cookbook_file '/home/user/work/somelocation/' do
  source ['folder-name/a.txt',''folder-name/b.txt'']
  mode "0644"
  action :create
end
```

I am aware of other means of copying files between arbitrary directories by looping through, but I am keen to know if there is more elegant way to handle directories akin to how cookbook_file handles files from standard folders inside cookbook's `files/default` directory.

Comment: Although the `source` accepts an array, you can't use this to specify multiple files to copy, instead read about [File Specificty](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html#file-specificity).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**remote_directory** allows you to copy a whole directory to a location of your choice. For example:

```
remote_directory "/etc/some_target_directory" do
  source 'local_directory' # <-- this is your directory in files/default/local_directory
  files_owner 'root'                                                                 
  files_group 'root'
  files_mode '0750'
  action :create
  recursive true                                                                      
end
```

Further reading: https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_directory.html

Comment: Is there a way to change `files/default` to something like `files/not-default`?

Comment: Yes, you can use arbitrary paths below `files/` (`default/` can even be omitted since couple of versions). There's also more in the [docs about file specificity](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html#file-specificity).

Answer (score 2):

There is AFAIK no "good/clean" way to copy all files that are contained in a cookbook.

In order to create multiple files, you can apply simple ruby logic to loop over these files:

```rb
['a.txt', 'b.txt'].each do |file|
  cookbook_file "/home/user/work/somelocation/#{file}" do
    source "folder-name/#{file}"
    mode "0644"
  end
end
```

This will create multiple `cookbook_file` resources (what [@jamesgaddum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2770825/jamesgaddum) is talking of).

P.S. the `default/` part in `files/default/` is optional since couple of Chef versions.

Comment: Is there a way to change `files/default` to something like `files/not-default`?

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely as `cookbook_file` uses a checksum to compare the existing and new file, so requires a unique `cookbook_file` resource for each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem and ATM the near thing to a solution I have is that in a recipe `run_context.cookbook_collection[<cookbook-name>].file_filenames` is an array with the complete path in destination for all the files under `<cookbook>/files`

for example in my config for a directory like this:

```
files/
  default/
     foo.txt
     bar.txt
     baz/foo.txt
```

It returns a directory like

```
[
  "/opt/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cookbook/files/default/foo.txt",
  "/opt/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cookbook/files/default/bar.txt",
  "/opt/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/cookbook/files/default/baz/foo.txt"
]
```

But this is not very useful to me